# Mnesia: time and space efficiency of read, match_object, select, and qlc queries

Tags: erlang, mnesia

Mnesia has four methods of reading from database: `read`, `match_object`, `select`, `qlc`. Besides their dirty counterparts of course. Each of them is more expressive than previous ones.

1. Which of them use indices?
2. Given the query in one of this methods will the same queries in more expressive methods be less efficient by time/memory usage? How much?

**UPD.**
As [I GIVE CRAP ANSWERS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25083/i-give-crap-answers) mentioned, `read` is just a key-value lookup, but after a while of exploration I found also functions `index_read` and `index_write`, which work in the same manner but use indices instead of primary key.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One at a time, though from memory:

- `read` always uses a Key-lookup on the `keypos`. It is basically the key-value lookup.
- `match_object` and `select` will optimize the query if it can on the `keypos` key. That is, it only uses that key for optimization. It never utilizes further index types.
- `qlc` has a query-compiler and will attempt to use additional indexes if possible, but it all depends on the query planner and if it triggers. `erl -man qlc` has the details and you can ask it to output its plan.

Mnesia tables are basically key-value maps from terms to terms. Usually, this means that if the *key* part is something the query can latch onto and use, then it is used. Otherwise, you will be looking at a full-table scan. This may be expensive, but do note that the scan is in-memory and thus usually fairly fast.

Also, take note of the table type: `set` is a hash-table and can't utilize a partial key match. `ordered_set` is a tree and can do a partial match:

Example - if we have a key `{Id, Timestamp}`, querying on `{Id, '_'}` as the key *is* reasonably fast on an `ordered_set` because the lexicographic ordering means we can utilize the tree for a fast walk. This is equivalent of specifying a composite INDEX/PRIMARY KEY in a traditional RDBMS.

If you can arrange data such that you can do simple queries without additional indexes, then that representation is preferred. Also note that additional indexes are implemented as bags, so if you have many matches for an index, then it is very inefficient. In other words, you should probably not index on a position in the tuples where there are few distinct values. It is better to index on things with many different (mostly) distinct values, like an e-mail address for a user-column for instance.

Comment: Am I right, that querying on `{'_', Timestamp}` on an `ordered_set` with key `{Id, Timestamp}` is a slow operation?

Comment: Yes, you are. It will have to scan the whole table in order to filter out the matching keys. Also note that a typical entry will look like `{atom(), {Id, Timestamp}, Value}` or something like that.

Comment: Just a small addition to this answer: newer versions of Erlang use duplicate_bag tables for storing mnesia indexes if the mnesia table is of type set or ordered_set. This removes a lot of the performance penalties associated with indexes on columns with lots of duplicate values (I only happen to know this because I wrote the patch myself ;-)